# move text up in align enviroment

Tags: math-mode, align

Move \text{} up in align enviroment.

How can I move the two text snippets closer (the lower text should MOVE UP):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 &       &  c\\
&   \ddots     &    \\
b&        & a_n
\end{pmatrix} &\qquad\qquad \text{text A}\\

&\qquad\qquad \text{text B}
\end{align*}
    
\end{document}
```

I want this:

[image]

Comment: What is the problem, exactly?

Comment: Is https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbhQn.png closer to the output you're interested in? If so, the `nicematrix` package may be useful: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{pNiceMatrix}[last-col]
a_1 &         &  c  & \text{text A} \\
    &  \ddots       &               \\
b   &         & a_n & \text{text B} \\
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\] 
\end{document}`

Comment: the "text B" text should be closer to "text A" if this would be a normal line break

Comment: Please, add a sketch of the intended result. By the way, `\vspace{100mm}` does nothing at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want something like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 &        & c \\
    & \ddots &   \\
b   &        & a_n
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad\qquad 
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
text A\\
text B
\end{tabular}
\end{equation*}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]